# Converting decimal to integer mule 4

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I have dataweave expression which is give value in decimal and I would like to convert it in to integer
allocation: $.PBSI__Inventory__r[0].PBSI__Real_Quantity__c, this like gives result 33.33 and need to convert it into 33.
Full Dataweave as below:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
{
    inventory @(xmlns:"http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/inventory/2007-05-31"):{
    "inventory-list": {
        header @("list-id":"Hastens_Inventory"):
         { 
             "default-instock":false,
             "use-bundle-inventory-only":false
         },
         records: {(payload map
         {
             record @("product-id": $.PBSI__Item__r.Name): {
                 allocation: $.PBSI__Inventory__r[0].PBSI__Real_Quantity__c,// **output value 33.33, expected output 33**
                 "allocation-timestamp": now()
             }
         })}

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your example should be focused on the question. Adding a 'full' script, that includes other non-related transformations, only adds noise.

Comment: Agree, I will make sure in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [floor()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-floor) function to round down a number.

Example:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var value=33.33
---
{
    original: value,
    floor: floor(value)
}
```